# Maven plugin error in netbeans

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using **macbook and netbeans** to write **javaFX** applications and I am now facing problem with this.

On my windows PC same code is working fine and as expected, but on mac program starts and when i press button to call action it just freezes so I have to force quit and then I get following message.

Please note that code is working fine on my other computer.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building IgraRecima 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ IgraRecima ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 13.684s
Finished at: Wed Aug 15 01:28:42 CEST 2018
Final Memory: 7M/309M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project IgraRecima: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 143 (Exit value: 143) -> [Help 1]
```

I was searching internet for answer and I could't get it right.

Comment: From a quick look around the internet I believe exit code 143 just means you killed the process. You should post the code that is causing the freeze (the `Button`'s action) or better yet create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not same version of Java on computers